# including diagbox changes unrelated picture

Tags: diagbox, picture-mode

Running the input

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(10,30)
\put(5,0){\vector(0,1){30}}
\end{picture}%
\end{document}
```

through `pdflatex` with and without `diagbox` produces different results, although `diagbox` should probably not influence unrelated environments.  It turns out that, under 8x magnification, including `diagbox` makes vector tips in picture look nicer:

[image: with diagbox (left) vs. without diagbox (right)]

Is it always the case or just in my example? What is going on internally?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `diagbox` loads `pict2e`, which redefines most of LaTeX's picture-mode commands to replace the old font-based approach by driver-specific draw instructions (that's why the output looks better with `diagbox` loaded).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oh, I see what goes on. Including diagbox and compiling with `latex` makes the arrow disappear from the DVI file. So, there is no free lunch :-(.

Comment: Well, yes, but do you _need_ the DVI file? Once you turn that into a PDF with `dvipdf`, the arrow shows up. Also, without `pict2e` you can't, for example, do `\vector(5,2)`... I see no serious drawback of using `pict2e`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sure, you are right. If I give up DVI, I could also give up picture altogether and use tikzpicture instead (which has drivers for both PS and PDF as far as I know).

Comment: Yes, that's also true. But why do you need DVI? (I'm curious now :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I do not really need DVI. However, sometimes the DVI files are really small with respect to their PDF or PS counterparts and are thus more suitable to be sent via e-mail. This is not always the case, though, and images have to be sent separately for DVI files. Further, DVI files are sometimes useful for debugging - in case font stuff goes wrong while running `pdflatex`, I sometimes try running `latex` to see where the problem roots may lie.

Comment: Indeed, the DVI format is usually shorter than PDF, mainly because PDF embeds fonts, while DVI searches them in the system.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments `diagbox` loads `pict2e` which by default loads driver-specific back end code for the drawing primitives (similar to the backend options of `graphics`, or `tikz`) so most of  the `picture` mode environment is redefined.

`pict2e` does however have an `original` option which uses the classic latex picture mode fonts for drawing, so you can specify that while still loading `diagbox` without affecting the picture mode arrows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[original]{pict2e}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(10,30)
\put(5,0){\vector(0,1){30}}
\end{picture}%
\end{document}
```